# How to sort and limit arithmetic mean of distributed data?

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing

Given multiple database nodes of key-value pairs (where key is non-unique), how to calculate top 1000 arithmetic means by key?

Calculating all arithmetic means and then sorting them is not an option due to sheer volume of data.

Viable approach could be somehow limiting key space to process but how?

Answer (score 0):

What is the cardinality of keys and database nodes ? Let's assume you have billions of keys and tens of database nodes. Let's call the number of nodes 'n'. Now, to solve this problem, we need three steps:

1. Find the subset of keys that are candidate for top 1000.
2. Compute their mean value by aggregating across all nodes.
3. Pick the top 1000 values from the result.

Let's look at the best possible algorithm for each step.

Find candidate Keys:

1. Each node computes local mean and local occurrence count for each key.
2. Now each node has (key, mean, occurrence) for each key.
3. Each node picks local top k where 1 < k <= 1000.
4. Each node finds the lowest mean value among local top k.
5. The value in step 4 is the local cut-off to select top k keys.
6. Now pick the minimum local cut offs across all nodes.
7. The value from step 6 is your global cut off. Only keys with higher mean that this global cut-off are considered in the next step.

Compute global mean and select top 1000:

1. Each node sends the local (key, mean, occurrence) for all keys with higher mean value than the global cutoff to a common node.
2. The common node computes mean for each key using the mean values and occurrences from each node.
3. The common node picks the top 1000.
4. If k is lower than 1000, the step 3 might not find 1000 unique keys, then we need to run another round excluding keys we selected.
5. Local mean computation doesn't need to repeat for next round, only the global cut off needs to change.

For the optimal solution, you need to tune the algorithm based on number of nodes, keys and key duplication across nodes.